# Can 2 different model rams can run well together?

Tags: memory

I want to combine 1666 mhz DDR3 4 gb ram with a 1666 mhz DDR3 8 gb ram.

Is there might be problem about it by motherboard and can they work good together?

I want a performance upgrade like %20.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This might be a tech support question, which is not on topic for Hardware Recs.

Comment: I agree it is not.  But where else would you ask this?  Anyway it has a funny answer:  "That depends...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes and without issue. However it will depend on the memory controller (Modern systems have moved this onto the CPU itself).

In almost all cases on modern systems you will see the RAM down-clock itself to match the lowest denominator of the chips, this might lower the FSB and the timings.

If one of the chips runs at an odd voltage however, I would not advise mixing them as the system likely won't finish POST.

Finally, if you have two banks for memory (1+2 & 3+4) generally the mismatched pair should sit on different banks. Refer to your motherboards manual for confirmation.

On the performance upgrade of 20%, we can't say without knowing what your utilization looks like and if RAM is the bottle neck. 4GB is a good minimum for just about any computer, doubling to 8GB+ will almost certainly provide a noticeably gain for most applications.

Comment: Thanks for answer Austin.

I found out that my ram is Hynix but the 8 gb ram I want to buy is Kingston.

In technical side both of them 1600 mhz,CL11.
The kingston is DDR3L not DDR3.In internet written that no difference between those but only voltage.DDRL3 lower voltage they say.

Comment: NOTE:Only 2 slots on my motherboard and I think to buy that 8 gb Kingston and run with my that 4 gb.

NOTE 2:I use i5 5th generation.Also I think to change my hdd to ssd.

Comment: Im waiting for ur answer.

Comment: @mockingbird I would not mix voltages, especially on the same channel. Look for plain DDR3.